# How to get Form data after posting in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, xmlhttprequest

Have form in `testPage.html`. And want to read form data in `testPageResult.html`

I have a html page `testPage.html` with form post action like below.

```
<h2>HTML Forms</h2>

<form action="http://test.com/testPageResult.html" method="POST" name="myForm">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="Mickey">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Mouse">
  <br><br>
  age<br>
  <input type="number" name="age">
  <br>
  email<br>
  <input type="email" name="email">
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I want to read the Form data in `testPageResult.html`

[image]

How to get the formdata which is mentioned in above pic.
Thanks

update: 
Trying to get `document.forms['myform']` but got undefined
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The **`FormData`** object lets you compile a set of key/value pairs to send using XMLHttpRequest. Its primarily intended for use in sending form data, but can be used independently from forms in order to transmit keyed data. The transmitted data is in the same format that the form's submit() method would use to send the data if the form's encoding type were set to "**multipart/form-data**".

However you can achieve it using simple Javascript like this

```
var formElements = document.forms['myform'].elements['inputTypeName'].value;
```

---

## Simple Eg

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="uniqueID" value="value" />
```

JS

```
var nameValue = document.getElementById("uniqueID").value;
```

Comment: getting undefined in `testPageresult.html`.
Question updated

Comment: tried. but got `null` 
Actually both are two different html pages. Thats why we can't able to get by name and id

Comment: use `localstorage`

Comment: But I am gonna host both html pages in two different site. In this case `localstorage` won't help I think

Comment: i think there is no solution for that

Comment: have you check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data) and [this](https://www.xul.fr/javascript/parameters.php)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208632/discussion-between-kiran-mistry-and-bcliks).